# get selected value of XSLT variable and set in Font

Tags: xml, xslt

i m having a variable declaration in XSL file as

```
<xsl:variable name="check" >
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(@style,'FONT-SIZE:'),'pt'))"/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

which give me font size as in my XML whatever it is 12,14,16

```
<xsl:template name="fontSize"> 
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="round($check=8) or round($check=7) or round($check=6)">
                    <font size="1" face="$Fface">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
                    </font>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="round($check=10) or round($check=9)">
                    <font size="2" face="$Fface">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
                    </font>
            </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
                    <font size="3" face="$Fface">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </font>         
          </xsl:otherwise>  
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

i make a template to select the size which i need from the choose query

and i want to get the selected size to set in the size attribute

```
<font size="$check"
              face="{normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(@style,'FONT-FAMILY:'),';'))}">
```

is m going correct or is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Can you show your current input XML, and you expected output, as that will make it easier to help you out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, replace this:

```
<xsl:variable name="check" >
      <xsl:value-of select="xxxxx"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

by this:

```
<xsl:variable name="check" select="xxxxx"/>
```

which is not only much more concise, it is also likely to be much more efficient. (This mistake seems to be very widespread.)

Second, I don't know whether this makes sense in the context of your overall project, but rather than generating font elements, the modern way is to use CSS. Output

```
<span class="c{$check}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
```

and then define CSS classes to control the detailed rendition.